# Change Git Repository for pull code

Tags: git, repository

I have a repository, say `abc/myprject.git`. I have this repo on a server from where I pull my code. Now I have forked this repository, naming it `chirag/myproject.git`.

I have two questions, with regards to this:

1. I want to use `chirag/myproject.git` repo instead of the original one now, so how do I change it on the server from `abc/myproject.git` to the forked one `chirag/myproject.git`?
2. And after I've changed the repo on the server, if I delete `abc/myproject.git`, will it cause any issues with `chirag/myproject.git`?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `git remote set-url` to change the URL of the `origin` remote (if you didn't change anything, the remote repository will be named `origin`).

   ```
   git remote set-url origin git://someserver/chirag/myproject.git
   ```
2. If there's no "physical" relationship between the both repositories at `abc/myproject.git` and `chirag/myproject.git` you won't run into any problems when deleting the first one. Git is a distributed version control system that produces full, independent repositories upon cloning.
   With "physical" relationship" I mean something like softlinks when both repositories reside on the same filesystem or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
git config -l
```

will display the remote origin (ie where the server will try and pull from)

You can remove the current remote with

```
git remote rm origin
```

and then add your new repo instead...

```
git remote add origin username@10.0.0.1:chirag/myproject.git
```

There shouldnt be a problem with then deleteing your original repo and just using the chirag one, although would suggest testing the new setup works before doing that.

You could also add the chirag repo as a second remote to the server, just call it something else eg

```
git remote add chirag username@10.0.0.1:chirag/myproject.git
```

And then just pull from it rather than origin

```
git pull chirag master
```

ps. throughout the example code I've assumed that on the server, the name of the remote to pull form is origin - change the name if its called something else

HTH
Doug